# Correct way to customise templates in CS-Cart

Tags: cs-cart

Sorry. I am totally new to CS-Cart.

I've inherited a site and its templates are located in a folder:

/design/themes/responsive/blocks/ etc

Is it correct to edit the *.tpl files in this location? Is this a custom theme area which is not overriden by an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your supposed to use the theme builder that is in the admin section of Cs-Cart. Here is some documentation that explains the process a little further. http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/themes/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Ty. Do you know what it means when a Theme is 'custom' . E.g. for the built-in responsive theme (CS-Cart 4.3.10) there are various 'flavours' e.g. Modern, Posh etc. What does it mean if it is custom? I've tried to clone a custom theme as per the tutorial (thanks) but it has not got any of the styling from the parent. I.e it looks like the default theme has been customised and you can't clone the customisations?

Comment: I would go into another theme ans copy the modern. You have themes but then you also have styles for thr theme.